# How can I update my smp server to a snapshot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to update my server to 12w41a, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4):

Mojang host the snapshots on their site, here is [12w41a](http://www.mojang.com/2012/10/minecraft-snapshot-12w41a/).

Just download and run as you would the normal server jar.